# Using my ebooks to drive traffic to my site

Tags: seo, ebooks

A person I'm working for has written a number of books on a subject he works as a consultant in (Sharepoint development). Little of his customer base come from organic searches. His ebooks are full of keywords pertaining to google-able problems of his customers.

Is there a way to associate the keywords in these books with his site?

Comment: E-books, depending upon the format, are searchable, however, while this was a trend years ago, e-books found in search do not convert to web users very well. They are considered "stickies" and engage a user found in search. In otherwords, for web search that results in web pages, e-books can help engage your users. However, for web search that results in an e-book does not generally convert a user to a web site. Also consider that e-books can be taken away and there is little to no need to return to a website. From a marketing perspective, e-books are good but fraught with danger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could publish entire ebooks on the website.  Allow users to read some number of pages from the book before preventing them from seeing more.   Make sure you have clear links to buy the book.

Let Google crawl and index the books under their [first click free](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40543?hl=en) policy.   Allow Googlebot to crawl and index all the pages without restriction.   Allow users to view at least three pages before preventing them from continuing for free.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, excellent strategic thinking on your part. Marked this as the answer.